# R Replace Keys of Multiple Columns with a Key Data frame

Tags: r, key, match

I have a dataset with 100 questions (below I have a subset with 3 questions).
I want to replace all the answer IDs with the actual answers provided in the "answer" dataset. The final result is shown in the "result" data frame.

data

```
 name   q1   q2  q3
 1      a    1    3  7 
 2      a    8    3  1
 3      a    3    9  2
 4      b   4    4  3
```

answer

```
 id   str  
    1   TRUE   
    2   FALSE   
    3   YES   
    4   NO
    5   LESS   
    6   MORE   
    7   GREATER   
    8   LESS
    9   NONE   
   10  DAILY
```

result

```
  name     q1   q2     q3
1    a    TRUE  YES   GREATER
2    a    LESS  YES   TRUE
3    a    YES   NONE  FALSE
4    b    NO    NO    YES
```

Answer (score 5):

We can `match` the elements of the dataset ('df1', without the 'name' column)  with the 'id' from 'answer' to get the numeric index (in this case we don't need `match`.  In general, it may be safer to use `match`) and get the corresponding 'str'.

```
 df1[-1] <- answer$str[match(as.matrix(df1[-1]), answer$id)]
 df1
 # name   q1   q2      q3
 #1    a TRUE  YES GREATER
 #2    a LESS  YES    TRUE
 #3    a  YES NONE   FALSE
 #4    b   NO   NO     YES
```

Or use `lookup` from `qdapTools` which can take  `key/value` columns as a 'data.frame' (ie. 'answer') and get the matching values

```
 library(qdapTools)
 df1[-1] <- lookup(unlist(df1[-1]), answer)
```

Or

```
 df1[-1] <- with(answer, setNames(str, id))[as.character(unlist(df1[-1]))]
```

Comment: Great idea with assigning the values to the existing df. I created a new one. +1

Comment: @plafort I did see yours.  It depends whether the OP wants to change the initial dataset or not.  +1 (already gave)

Comment: Is there a way to pass my function `answer$str[x]` to `sapply` without the anonymous func?

Comment: @plafort Try `Map('[',list(answer$str), df1[-1])`

Comment: I found another way with `as.matrix`

Comment: Yes, it will require the ids to be in order, and non-repeating

Comment: @plafort Sorry, I couldn't find a way with `sapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Or use indexing:

```
data[-1] <- sapply(data[-1], function(x) answer$str[x])
#   name   q1   q2      q3
# 1    a TRUE  YES GREATER
# 2    a LESS  YES    TRUE
# 3    a  YES NONE   FALSE
# 4    b   NO   NO     YES
```

Larger tasks can be broken down to simplified examples to test methods. Create a vector with `q1` values only. `v <- c(1,8,3,4)` If we can replace these four, it is quite possible to scale the operation:

```
answer$str[v]
[1] TRUE LESS YES  NO
```

This creates the first question column. The remainder of the code is repeating that process for each column.

**Edit**

A quicker way without `sapply`. It will work as long as the lookup list is in order and is non-repeating:

```
data[-1] <- answer$str[as.matrix(data[-1])]
#   name   q1   q2      q3
# 1    a TRUE  YES GREATER
# 2    a LESS  YES    TRUE
# 3    a  YES NONE   FALSE
# 4    b   NO   NO     YES
```